# Как спрятать затемненный фон

Tags: javascript, jquery

Подскажите пожалуйста почему не работает, при нажатии на ссылку фон вокруг затемняется, а вот при нажатии на ту же ссылку или на сам фон, затемненный фон не исчезает.

```js
$('.sticks-block a').click(function(){
  console.log('$(".backbg").show();');
  $(".backbg").show();
});


$('div.backbg').click(function(){
  console.log('$(".backbg").hide();');
  $(".backbg").hide();
});
```

```css
body {
  padding:0px;
  margin:0px;
}
.backbg {
  position:absolute;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  background: gray;
  opacity:0.5;
  margin:0px;
  /*border:1px solid black;*/
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="sticks-block">
  <a id="toggler" class="" href="#"> 
    <div class="backbg" style="display:none;"></div> 
      <img src="/assets/img/note.png" alt=""><img src="/assets/img/nn.png" alt="" style="display:none;">
       <span>Заметки</span></a>
<div id="mydiv" style="display:none;">
    <form>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Введите текст"><button type="submit">Добавить заметку</button>
    </form>
</div>       
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Так как `div.backbg` находится внутри `.sticks-block a`, при клике на `div.backbg` событие всплывает до `.sticks-block a`, и код первого обработчика выполняется опять - после второго.

```
$('div.backbg').click(function(evt){
    $(".backbg").hide();
    evt.stopPropagation();
});
```

или

```
<div class="sticks-block">
  <div class="backbg" style="display:none;"></div>
  <a id="toggler" class="" href="#"> 
    ...
```